# How to get rid of default label in EditorForModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, editorfor, editorformodel

I have an ASP.Net MVC project that I'm working on and I have a model that I want to turn into I form.  I want to use `EditorForModel()` for this because I want it to automatically add fields to the form if I decide to add/remove properties to the model later.

The problem I'm having is that editor for model takes each property and creates the following HTML: (this is just generic. not the actual code)

```
<div class="editor-label"><label>Label Title</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input type="type"/></div
```

However what I want it do do for each field is this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <label>Label Title</label>
    <input type="type"/>
</div>
```

But if I try to do this in an editor template I get this instead:

```
<div class="editor-label"><label>Label Title</label></div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <label>Label Title</label>
    <input type="type"/>
</div>
```

How can I get `EditorForModel()` to not make it's own label field?  I know I could always style it as hidden in CSS but it'd be nice if it wasn't even there to begin with so I could limit code confusion.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I've also tried using `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]` but this just hides the entire field and not just the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write this in your editor template cshtml to get it work as expected:

```
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    <div class="editor-field">
        <label>@property.GetDisplayName()</label>
        @Html.Editor(property.PropertyName)
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I put this in a string.cshtml and it did a really weird thing where it ran this multiple times per string property.  Does it need to go into it's own model editor template instead of a type editor template.

For example my model has 4 string properties and 2 integer properties. does this code go into a ModelName.cshtml or a String.cshtml?

Comment: If you have a specific model then create the model `[TypeName].chstml`  the editor template. If it is generic then create `Object.cshtml` template in the same folder. In your view you should just call `@Html.EditorForModel()` only to do it work.

Comment: The template must be in EditorTemplates folder by the way.

Comment: Really quick question not really related to this.  If I need to check if a property is required in an editor template I know I can use the property.IsRequired.  But this returns true for Value Types.  Is there a way to check if a Value type has actually been set as required?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143053/discussion-between-joe-higley-and-codenotfound).

Comment: ValueType are required by default. If you want to remove that requirement you must use Nullable<T> where T is the ValueType.